# PHP header redirect not working after update query

Tags: php, mysql, redirect

I am sending a verification link to an email address.  The link will direct the user to a page with only a small amount of code.  I am essentially just changing one row in my database from a "0" to a "1" indicating they have been verified

## PHP:

```
<?php

    include( 'database/sql_link.php' ) ;   //This is my link to the database


    $clientName = mysqli_real_escape_string( $db , $_GET[ 'client' ] ) ;

    $sql        =   " UPDATE  clients
                         SET  verifiedUser = '1'
                       WHERE  userName     = '$clientName' " ;

    if ( !mysqli_query( $db , $sql ) ) {

        die( ' Error: <br> <br> ' . mysqli_error( $db ) ) ;

    }

    header( "Location: http://www.example.net/portal.php" ) ;

    exit() ;
```

The code above will modify the database properly, but it won't redirect to "portal.php".

Any input is appreciated.  Thanks in advance!

## Edit - Solved by Shehary - details below in my reply to the thread.

Comment: you like the code having this much unnecessary spaces, wondering if you write `p h p` instead of `php`

Comment: these kind of gaps and spaces, in long run, will give you error `header already sent` and add `ob_start();` on top after `<?php` see if this helps

Comment: You were suggesting that my spacing `is` causing issues, or that spacing can cause issues?  Because i know the latter.  If you believe that my use of spacing above is causing a problem then I would GREATLY appreciate some clarification into where the spacing is misused above.  Thanks

Comment: Does your problem solved or you still struggling with it?

Comment: Have you checked the logs? Are `error_reporting` and `display_errors` enabled?

Comment: @Shehary  you were totally right.  I have updated my solved reply below.  I had a space before the leading `<?php` in my sql_link.php file.  Removed the tab.  Thanks for your help.

Comment: @ferdynator  I enabled `error_reporting` and that is what lead me to discovering the spacing issues in my sql_link file that Shehary was warning about.  Thanks for the help.

Comment: Please add the solution as an answer to your question.  Don't just put in an edit saying it has been solved.

Comment: @ Toby Allen  If you scroll down to my answer its all there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So my problem was rooted in my initial database link php file.

`include( 'database/sql_link.php' );`

the file had a tab before the starting `<?php`.

Thanks to  Shehary.

## Updated PHP

```
<?php
error_reporting(-1);
include( 'database/sql_link.php' ) ;
$clientCompany = mysqli_real_escape_string( $db , $_GET[ 'comp'    ] ) ;
$clientName    = mysqli_real_escape_string( $db , $_GET[ 'client'  ] ) ;
$clientAddress = mysqli_real_escape_string( $db , $_GET[ 'address' ] ) ;
$sql         =   " UPDATE clients SET verifiedUser = '1' WHERE userName = '$clientName' " ;
if ( !mysqli_query( $db , $sql ) ) {
    die( ' Error: <br> <br> ' . mysqli_error( $db ) ) ;
}
header( "Location: http://www.etheritwiki.net/evanJustinProject_Portal_Client.php" ) ;
exit() ;
$db  -> close() ;
$sql -> free()  ;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
include( 'database/sql_link.php' ) ;   //This is my link to the database


$clientName = mysqli_real_escape_string( $db , $_GET[ 'client' ] ) ;

$sql        =   " UPDATE  clients
                     SET  verifiedUser = '1'
                   WHERE  userName     = '$clientName' " ;

if ( !mysqli_query( $db , $sql ) ) {
    die( ' Error: <br> <br> ' . mysqli_error( $db ) ) ;
}

header( "Location: http://www.example.net/portal.php" ) ;
exit() ;
```

Try this instead.

Comment: Thanks for your help.  I updated my code to reflect what you recommend.  No dice, it updates the database and then hangs on a blank screen.